# What type of weapon is Nnoitra's zanpakuto?

Tags: bleach

In the Espada Arc, Kenpachi fights Nnoitra.I was trying to explain Nnoitra to my friend but I couldn't figure out what kind of weapon it was, is it a scythe or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nnoitra's zanpakuto, Santa Maria, is unique in regards to what type of weapon it is.

Unreleased, it resembles an axe with two crescents or a halberd, with it's edges rotated by 90 degrees.

[image: Unreleased]

But due to the placement of the blade edges, it resembles a scythe more so than an axe.

When released, it resembles a scythe:

[image: Resurreccion]

But note that when he was the 8th-ranked Espada, his weapon resembled a staff with a giant crescent:

[image: Flashback!]

Note that it does a similar motif to the Chinese [monk's spade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monk%27s_spade) (aka Crescent Moon Spade) weapon that's like a halberd.

[image: Yue Ya Chan]